# DetailedApiRequestError in Google Sheets API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-sheets-api, flutter-android

I trying to create a spread sheet in using Google Sheets API, I have Enabled **Google Sheets API** in console in google cloud but still getting error.
[image: Enabled Google Sheets API]

**Below Is Code I am Using.**

```
final authClient =
        await GoogleSignInProvider.googleSigniIn.authenticatedClient();
    if (authClient != null) {
      final SheetsApi sheetapi = SheetsApi(authClient);
      Spreadsheet sheet = Spreadsheet();
      sheet.properties?.title = 'Title';

      sheet = await sheetapi.spreadsheets.create(sheet);
      log(sheet.spreadsheetId.toString());
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
Exception has occurred.DetailedApiRequestError (DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Google Sheets API has not been used in project xxxxxxxxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxxxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.))
```

I have already tried Enabling And Disabling it.
How Can I Solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a Google Sheet you need to have Google Drive API permission.